# Sort values by date within a single cell using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have values like

"
02-Mar - blablabla

02-Jan - blablabla"

Given in a single cell, in multiple rows for a single column.

How do I sort this by date like:
"
02-Jan - blablabla

02-Mar - blablabla"

Also, this needs to be done whenever this particular cell is edited. When the cell gets edited and a new text is added - a timestamp gets added on the left side of this new text

So if today was 03-July and I added something new to the above cell, it would become:
"
02-Jan - blablabla

02-Mar - blablabla

03-July newtext"

I can sort this using Google sheets formulas easily using a combination of split, flatten and join, but this uses another column. I want to do the same thing using app script over the same column the new text is being entered.

Answer (score 0):

Sort Date within a single cell:

```
function sortSingleCell() {
  const mA =["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","July","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue();
  let arr = vs.match(/\d{2}[ -]+(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|July|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[^\d{2}]+/gm);
  arr.sort((a,b) => {
    let ta = a.split(/[ -]/);
    let vA = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),mA.indexOf(ta[1].trim()),ta[0].trim()).valueOf();
    let tb = b.split(/[ -]/);
    let vB = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),mA.indexOf(tb[1].trim()),tb[0].trim()).valueOf();
    return vA - vB;
  });
  Logger.log(arr.join(""))
  sh.getRange("A1").setValue(arr.join(""))
}
```

Cell Data:

```
" 02-Mar - blablabla

02-Jan - blablabla"

Given in a single cell, in multiple rows for a single column.

How do I sort this by date like: " 02-Jan - blablabla

02-Mar - blablabla"

Also, this needs to be done whenever this particular cell is edited. When the cell gets edited and a new text is added - a timestamp gets added on the left side of this new text

So if today was 03-July and I added something new to the above cell, it would become: " 02-Jan - blablabla

02-Mar - blablabla

03-July newtext"
```

Sorted Cell Data:

```
02-Jan - blablabla"

Given in a single cell, in multiple rows for a single column.

How do I sort this by date like: " 02-Jan - blablabla

02-Jan - blablabla

02-Mar - blablabla

02-Mar - blablabla"

Also, this needs to be done whenever this particular cell is edited. When the cell gets edited and a new text is added - a timestamp gets added on the left side of this new text

So if today was 02-Mar - blablabla

03-July and I added something new to the above cell, it would become: " 03-July newtext"
```

Comment: Hey, is there a way for me to delete the data in the cells and then retain it after entering? For example, the cell has "02-Jan - randomtext" and then I decide to edit-->delete this text--> add "randomtext2", the output would become "02-Jan - randomtext '\n' 03-Jan - randomtext2

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: ok, forget the question above for a minute. let's suppose I have a fresh sheet. I enter "xyz" on any random column/row. I then replace "xyz" with "abc". Can my cell display "abc, xyz"? Remember, I have replaced the text "xyz"

Comment: Presumably there a cell the `01 - Jan - sometextxyz` and you replace xyz with abc so know you have 01 - Jan - sometextabc` and if I understand your question you wish your cell to contain "abc, xyz"? Why?

Comment: that was just an example. Now I am facing the challenge of archiving the text. So suppose i hover over the cell and type, it replaces the old cell data. I want to retrieve that lost data. For example: a cell has the text "xyz", I hovered over that cell and decided to type "abc", now this "abc" would have replaced "xyz" and I would have lost this data. Is there a way to get something like "xyz, abc" when I type new info? Suppose I type "newinfo1" after this replacing the old data, this should look something like. " xyz, abc, newinfo1" using onedit or onselectionchange functions

Comment: You could store an array of revision in the cell notes

Comment: Can I store it within the same cell? As explained in the example? I can use those timestamps to get them in ascending order?

Comment: Sure that's what notes are.  But they don't show up visually except for the little dark triangle in the upper right corner

Comment: I use cell notes to store data that's necessary for me to access the event in apps script should I wish to edit it so I store everything in JSON so that it's easy to  bring it back in as an object

Comment: Right, but in this case I want to be able to bring them back as text on the same cell instead of notes. Is this even possible? Notes won't work cause i'll be extracting data from the cells.

Comment: JSON is just a string

Comment: but wouldn't JSON format look ugly with all the {} and stuff? I just want a clean data saying "data - random text", I know I sound like a newb cause a lot of this is new to me haha.

Comment: You can't see the note unless you hover above the triangle so why care what it looks like.  It's just there to collect a few revisions.  But you can do whatever you want.

Comment: It's not about the notes or the JSON format. Main thing is I need the data within the cell itself, visually visible without any hovering required, even if the cell was modified.

Comment: I guess I miss understand.  I thought you wanted a place to store revisions.

Comment: isn't it storing revisions as well? I feel like I am very close to cracking this with but just need an example of some sort. How would you go about doing this with a trigger function? So suppose a cell has "xyz", I replaced this cell with "abc", the end result in that cell automatically become "xyz, abc", in that order. So it is storing the old data somewhere, and putting it back with the new one, all in an ascending order of as old data,new data...

Comment: There's a Range.setNotes() and Range.setNote() which behave similar to setValue and setValues()

Comment: so ur saying store the data using setnote first, then retrieve that data from notes and copy it in the cells?

Comment: Actually I'd probably store the last five revisions in the notes

Comment: Hey, I figured it out! thank you so much! Just one minor problem that I am facing is the duplicates within the string. So suppose I have a string like "xyz, abc, xyz", is there a way I can remove a duplicate from a string?

Comment: Probably with indexOf()